# Hot or not; Tweak the Top Questions list to discard poor questions

Tags: feature-request, top-questions

The following question has a score of **-1** votes, and **4** close votes: https://superuser.com/questions/419400/where-can-i-buy-micro-express-microflex-23b-in-europe

I do not think it should be included in the **Top Questions** list. Also, notice the `[closed]` question above it! That being said, I think the algorithm needs an update, at least to reflect that some questions are poor fits for the site:

1. If the question has a score greater than **N** votes, include it, **else**,
2. If the question is closed, do not include it.
3. If the question has more than **3** close votes, do not include it.
4. If the question has a score of less than **0** votes and if there are **no** answers, do not include it.

---

Screenshots:

[image: Top Questions]

[image: 419400]

Comment: If you listed some things you wanted to change with the algorithm, then it would be a feature-request. But as it is, reads like support

Comment: @random Thanks. I could come up with a few suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

### Example:

- https://superuser.com/questions/419503/how-to-reset-unlock-code-in-nokia-x2-01, a -2 score closed question

  [image: hot question 1]

  Hotness: `ln(19)*4 + ((0*(-2))/5) + 0` divided by `3 - 0` (two hours old) = **3,92**
- Below that in the list: [Why are the failing addresses in Memtest86+ higher than my total memory?](https://superuser.com/questions/419496/why-are-the-failing-addresses-in-memtest86-higher-than-my-total-memory) (there's a +2 score answer, and 2h was the answer date, and that doesn't count)

  [image: hot question 2]

  Hotness: `ln(25)*4 + ((1*1)/5) + 2` divided by `4 - 0` (three hours old) = **3,76**

(I totally disregard that age isn't just integers. It'll probably only get worse for very recent questions)

Works as designed. It's just the algo that sucks.

- Very recent questions are hot by design
- Getting some views is better than some score and answers
- Question score doesn't matter if there are no answers

Unsurprising, since the algorithm was designed with SO's traffic and voting and answering behavior in mind.

---

Let's see...

[image: screenshot of two very different questions]

- `ln(13)*4+(1*1/5)+1` divided by `1.35` is about `8.5`
- `ln(79000)*4+(326*2/5)+679)` divided by `(33-((32-20)/2)^1.5)` is about `31.7`

Now **that** one I don't get... unless `Qage` and `Qupdated` are measured in minutes, resulting in hotness scores of `0.55` and `0.54`, respectively, making younger question *much hotter* using this scoring. Clearly, the rules aren't made with our rather slow uptake of question scores and views in mind.

---

### Update 2

In case you wondered about the following:

[image: Screenshot of boring 0 score question above Carmack question]

These are the numbers (`Qage` and `Qupdated` really are in minutes):

- Three hours old, 0 score, 0 answers, 16 views:

  `(ln(16)+(0*0/5)+0)/(180-((180-180)/2)^1.5) = 0.15403`
- Five days old, 93k views, 437 score, three answers with 861 combines score:

  `(ln(93729)+(3*437/5)+861)/(7680-((7680-7410)/2)^1.5) = 0.150384`

Clearly, age is way overemphasized in the algorithm. That it doesn't have minimum values for score, answer count, or views is also a problem.

Comment: From my experience, "bad" questions attract just as many views as good ones (and definitely more than the average ones). As a start, views should only be taken into account if the post has no negative score. Especially when there are no answers.

Comment: As a contrived example, a 55 views topic with no answers and arbitrary (e.g. negative) score is *slightly hotter* than a 12 views, 5 score topic with 2 answers, scored +3 and +1 created at the same time.

Comment: Unit of time is mostly relevant for edits, when `Qupdated` != `Qage`, but because of the `+1` zero-division protection, it'll also affect recent topics very strongly (`1+1 : 1` is very different from `60+1 : 60`).

Answer (score 2):

There is [a specific formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/139837) which determines the hotness score.

```
(log(Qviews)*4) + ((Qanswers * Qscore)/5) + sum(Ascores)
--------------------------------------------------------
((Qage+1) - ((Qage - Qupdated)/2)) ^ 1.5
```

I'm really not sure how that one got selected. Could be a bug.

Comment: Easy: If there are no answers, the score doesn't matter. What's left is the views divided by a very small divisor, as with all very recent posts high up on the *(not so) hot* list.

Comment: @DanielBeck that doesn't really make sense. If `Qanswers` is 0, then then that whole term of the equation is 0, and `sum(Ascores)` is _also_ 0, so the overall score should be lower than if there were answers, because the numerator is going to be smaller.

Comment: Check out the screenshot with three very recent questions being considered hot. Due to their very little age, it doesn't matter that they get all their hotness from their views. I just explained why the negative score isn't relevant, since the user didn't highlight the other 0 score or 0 answer topics in the screenshot.

Comment: @DanielBeck ah, I see better what you mean now. Thanks for showing that. The hotness algorithm does tend to be... pretty bad.